# Is there a definitive way to determine if string is base64 in .NET

Tags: .net, string, parsing, type-conversion, base64

I have been trying to do a simple task of running a bunch of strings trough code and telling which of them are base64 and which are not. I Currently use code as follows:

```
Span<byte> buffer = new Span<byte>(new byte[pair.Value.Length]); // Set's the length to the string length.


Convert.TryFromBase64String(pair.Value, buffer, out int val4) // Tries to convert string to byte array (from base64)
```

The main issue is that if I pass it a string "TEST" it thinks it's a base64 string.... Basically any uppercase string that has no special characters is considered a base64. Is there any way to check if the string is base64 or not ? I know it might be impossible, but if anybody has any ideas it would be appreciated.

Comment: No, you can only detect that a string is NOT base64 because of the presence of invalid characters other than whitespace.  This comment is perfectly valid Base64.  If you have additional context to apply besides "is it valid" then you can use that context as a separate test, for example "is the binary length a multiple of 32" or "dies the binary begin with the prefix for a PNG file" but that is separate from it being Base64.

Comment: @DaveS that's a valid comment. Maybe you would have some suggestions. As yes it's true I basically receive a big json with a bunch of fields. And most of them are just simple strings but one or two are files encoded as base64. So basically I need to figure out which of the strings I just treat normally and which ones do I treat as files, but the issue is it might be just a simple text file, not a png :(

Comment: There's always this :D https://dotnetfiddle.net/nyoAcf

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Not sure what you mean by that. This is exactly what my problem is - TEST is not a valid base64 I mean it is valid, but not what I need. I do realize it's impossible to determine which ones are base64 and which ones are strings. I will try different approach now.

Comment: If you know the maximum length of non-file json entries are under 2,000 characters and all files are at least 2000 characters you can use a test like that.  Aren't TXT files still going to be encoded as Base64?  If not, is there a JSON entry telling you the file name like "mydoc.txt" that would tell you it is not encoded?  Like I said above, you can other context, but we don't know what context you have available.

Comment: @DaveS Huge thanks, your context idea gave me insight and I managed to do it. What I decided to do. Not sure if that is a great approach. But when I get the file in API it is in Base64 and then when doing return(object) it is converted to base64. What I am going to do is write a json converter for Byte[] that adjusts the default behaviour by adding BASE64 at the beggining of Base64 string and then I can just check if StartsWith(BASE64), Sounds like it should work.